# Unable to render anything but default Rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following a tutorial (https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/static-pages-ruby-rails) to render a page using Rails routes. The problem is I get an error instead of the page that should render. I don't know what I'm doing wrong since there are literally only a few steps.

The only difference my code has from the tutorial is trivial. I'm using `Videos` rather than `Pages.`

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    # This means that all paths following the pattern:
    # /videos/about, /videos/home, /videos/features
    # will route here!
    get "/videos/:video" => "videos#show"
end
```

In `app/controllers/videos_controller.rb"`:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
    def show
        render template: "videos/#{params[:page]}"
    end
end
```

Finally, I have a static page filled with gibberish stored in `app/views/videos/videos.html.erb`.

However, when I run my server and go to `0.0.0.0:3000/videos/` I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/videos"
Rails.root: /home/mightu/Desktop/portal_rails
```

When I try `0.0.0.0:3000/videos/pizza`, I get:

```
Missing template /videos with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/mightu/Desktop/portal_rails/app/views"
```

It tells me the problem is this line:

```
render template: "videos/#{params[:page]}"
```

Please help thx

Comment: What URL are you visiting to trigger that error from the server?

Comment: Just edited: ```0.0.0.0:3000/videos/```. I tried adding ```videos/pizza/``` and it gave me a FUNKY error (will edit).

Comment: Why do you have the double curly braces here: `"videos/#{{params[:page]}}"`?

Comment: @jvillian Thanks for catching that. Just got rid of it, will update.

Comment: After editing, is your error still the same for `0.0.0.0:3000/videos/pizza`?

Comment: Yeah it is, "Template is missing" it says

Comment: That's not the same error. Please add the new error and the `show` template to your question.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean "add" the show template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194719/discussion-between-jvillian-and-mcfloofenbork).

Comment: Just so you know, this method can potentially create insecurities (https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/dynamic_render_paths/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by doing:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :videos
end
```

Which will give you:

```
     videos GET    /videos(.:format)             videos#index
            POST   /videos(.:format)             videos#create
  new_video GET    /videos/new(.:format)         videos#new
 edit_video GET    /videos/:id/edit(.:format)    videos#edit
      video GET    /videos/:id(.:format)         videos#show
            PATCH  /videos/:id(.:format)         videos#update
            PUT    /videos/:id(.:format)         videos#update
            DELETE /videos/:id(.:format)         videos#destroy
```

Then, rename `app/views/videos/videos.html.erb` to `app/views/videos/show.html.erb`.

And modify your `show` action on your `VideosController` to:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def show

  end
end
```

And now `0.0.0.0:3000/videos/pizza` will render the `show.html.erb` template and you'll have a `params[:id]` with a value of `pizza`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the routes to `/videos`, You can either add a `resources :videos` if you need all the restful routes or just 
`get 'videos', to: 'videos#index'`.

You have only defined the route for a `show` action but you are trying to get the `index` page for videos, you can look into details of routing [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I thought the ```videos/:videos``` in routes makes it so that any thing that starts with ```videos``` calls the show action. Why would it go to the index page.

Comment: I'd suggest `resources :videos, only: [:show]` if the OP only wants the `show` action.